# How to boot from an OS inside an HDD of another PC?

Tags: boot

I've taken out the internal HDD of a laptop and when I try to boot from it on a newer laptop, BSOD happens, but it's fine when I boot from it in the original laptop. I'd like to know what are the possible ways to boot from an HDD of a completely different machine without BSOD? Are there any tools for it, like virtual machines?

Or in a case of forensics trying to get a full access/replica of the OS of an HDD itself, how do they do it?

EDIT: I meant to do this on Windows, or Linux.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the OS you are attempting to do this on. I assume it’s Windows, but gotta be clear.

Comment: What is your end goal, what are you trying to accomplish? Just plugging an HDD with a Windows OS into a new computer and powering it on will almost certainly cause significant issues, including BSODs. So if we understand what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to provide alternate solutions to reach that goal.

Comment: @music2myear I'm trying to load and run on my PC the old OS on an HDD from another computer, either directly or through something like VirtualBox. Something like simulation. For example, you sold your old computer but just left the HDD, now you want to boot from that old HDD on a different computer.

Comment: The reason you encounter a BSOD is due to the hardware differences.  There is no easy way to avoid this problem, besides how you acomplish this for Windows, is entirely different than if you were using Linux.  Asking for both processes is extremely broad.  In the case of forensics, they would use the original hardware, after duplicated the HDD.

Comment: Some version of Windows are OEM versions that don't react well to new hardware - they have very limited driver support, for example.  It can be a nightmare trying to even get a HDD to SSD clone (from an upgrade) working sometimes.  Linux is normally very robust *by comparison* in my experience, but even Linux can e.g. require the bootloader (usually Grub2) to be updated or reinstalled.

Comment: @Ramhound I think I found the solution. [Here](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) I tried this method and it works but in the Windows loading screen, the following error terminates the machine in VirtualBox: The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium &quot;ahci-0-0&quot; (rc=VERR_ACCESS_DENIED). Make sure there is enough free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly. Operation can be resumed afterwards.

Error ID: BLKCACHE_IOERR
Severity: Non-Fatal Error

Answer (score 1):

This depends highly on the version of Windows you have.  Windows 7 & 8 are pretty good, but I found Windows 10 to be slightly better.

Older versions of windows will vary highly.

The simplest option if you have the old computer is sysprep, and its built into windows.

Good idea to make sure you have a copy of the windows key on hand, just in case.

On the old computer, boot system:

First make sure there is no unattended.xml in c:\windows\system32\sysprep

from and administrative command prompt:

```
c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep /generalize /oobe /shutdown
```

When the computer turns off place the hard drive in the new computer and turn it on.

The process will take as much as 30-45 minutes, but windows should adopt the new hardware.

As a precaution I strong suggest getting the Storage Controller drivers(IDE/SATA) for the new computer in advance.  Extracting them so the .INF file in visible.  Then pre-injecting it.

```
pnputil /add-driver x:\driver.inf
```

Everything else you will need to install new drivers for after the fact.

---

You can also force ably down grade your Storage Controller drivers into "Standard IDE" mode through the device manager.

This is more of hack, but I have had it work more than once.

Don't expect much to work, before you install all new drivers.

Comment: I don't have any access to the old computer.